# Не подскажите, как реализовать эффект скролла спаралксом

Tags: reactjs, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на реакте реализовать, скролл как на этом сайте, с помощью каких библиотек?

[www.studiorhe.com/](http://www.studiorhe.com/)

Answer (score 0):

такое?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-horizontal-scrolling-menu
смотри демку, по ссылке